# nginx location does not interpret php

Tags: php, nginx

I'am going crazy to understand this nginx vhost config. My issue is with the /v2 location, it does not send php stuff to php-fpm while it works properly outside /v2. Can anyone point me the mistake ?

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  include ssl.conf;
   include hardening.conf;
   server_name myapp.domain.com myapp;
   ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/myapp.domain.com.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/myapp.domain.com.key;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-access.log main;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-error.log notice;
   root /var/www/html/myapp.domain.com;

   location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
   }

   location ~ /v2 {
     alias /var/www/html/myapp.domain.com/version-2/web;
     try_files $uri index.php$is_args$args;
   }

   location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
     if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
       return 404;
     }

     # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
     fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

     fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params.conf;
   }
 }
```

According to comments, I'm trying the nested location solution but I receive now 404 when I try `https://myapp.domain.com/v2/index.php` while `/var/www/html/myapp.domain.com/version-2/web/index.php` is present on the filesystem. Also as explained on the link given, I modified my location from `^` to `^~`. Any idea what's wrong?

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  include ssl.conf;
   include hardening.conf;
   server_name myapp.domain.com myapp;
   ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/myapp.domain.com.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/myapp.domain.com.key;
   access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-access.log main;
   error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-error.log notice;
   root /var/www/html/myapp.domain.com;

   location ~ /\.ht {
     deny  all;
   }

   location ^~ /v2 {
     alias /var/www/html/myapp.domain.com/version-2/web;
     try_files $uri index.php$is_args$args;

     location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
       fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
       if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
         return 404;
       }

       # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
       fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

       fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
       fastcgi_index index.php;
       include fastcgi_params.conf;
     }

   }

   location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
     if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
       return 404;
     }

     # Mitigate https://httpoxy.org/ vulnerabilities
     fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";

     fastcgi_pass localhost:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params.conf;
   }
 }
```

Comment: You have two PHP apps with different roots. You will need two different `location` blocks to process the `.php` URIs. Consider using a nested `location` blocks - like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287201/wordpress-laravel-and-nginx/45297857#45297857).

Comment: @RichardSmith I updated the post with your proposal but now I get some 404 as explained in the post, can you have a look again please ?

Comment: `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` does not work with `alias`, use: `$request_filename` instead. Also, you need to set a value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME`. Also, I would avoid using `try_files` and `alias` together due to [this issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

Comment: indeed I did not saw that detail, replacing the `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name` by `$request_filename` and replacing `try_files` by a rewrite rule also reording some stuff in the php location made it working.

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks a lot! Do I need to post the working version?

Comment: I you wish, you can post your working solution as an answer and accept it yourself. See [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, I got working config:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  include ssl.conf;
  include hardening.conf;
  server_name myapp.domain.com myapp;
  ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/myapp.domain.com.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/myapp.domain.com.key;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-access.log main;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/myapp.domain.com-error.log notice;
  root /var/www/html/myapp.domain.com;

  location ^~ /v2/admin/web/index[_dev]*.php/command {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      rewrite ^ /v2/admin/web/index.php$is_args$args last;
    }
  }

  location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
    if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
      return 404;
    }
    include fastcgi_params.conf;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to point to the php5-fpm location. like this:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
      include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Take a look in a whole example:

```
server {
    listen 8082;
    listen [::]:8082;
    server_name 192.168.2.60;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/phpmyadmin/;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;


    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?uri=$uri;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
     }

     location ~ /\.ht {
            deny all;
     }   
}
```