# How to config a laravel project in an exist php project with nginx alias?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

This is my existing project's nginx `config` file.I can access `sms.dev/index.php` .
Now,I want to deploy a new laravel project on the `/var/www/html/laravel` folder and use this domain like `sms.dev/laravel` to access my new laravel project.
How to do this ?

```
server{
        listen 80;
        server_name sms.dev;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        root /var/www/html/sms;
        location /laravel/ {
            # how to config it ?
        }
        location ~ .*\.(php|php5)?$
        {
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                include fcgi.conf;
        }

        if (!-e $request_filename) {
                return 404;
        }
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287201/wordpress-laravel-and-nginx/45297857#45297857).

Comment: The browser return 404 whatever I access.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;` inside your location block

```
location /laravel/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```