# Install Laravel with nginx in Subdirectory

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, config, nginx-config

I try to enable PHP for only one subdirectory (the laravel directory) but I didn't manage to get this working. NGINX is always saying 404 File not found or php says "no input file specifed". What am I doing wrong?

This is my location config:

```
        location /laravel {
        root   html/laravel/public;
        index   index.php index.html index.html;
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root   html/laravel/public;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            #include        fastcgi_params;
            include fastcgi.conf;
         }
     }
```

**UDPATE 1**: It seems that nginx does not properly evaluate my location expressions:

> 2018/09/12 16:30:44 [error] 26476#24408: *1 CreateFile() "C:/Server/nginx/html/index.php" failed (2: The system cannot find the file specified), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /laravel/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"

This is the wrong path and at least the root of the / location:

```
   location / {
        root   C:/Server/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    }
```

I tried to move the block but nothing changes.

**UPDATE 2**:
It seems that nginx is very buggy. The documentation states:

> Checks the existence of files in the specified order and uses the first found file for request processing; **the processing is performed in the current context. The path to a file is constructed from the file parameter according to the root and alias directives.** It is possible to check directory’s existence by specifying a slash at the end of a name, e.g. “$uri/”. If none of the files were found, an internal redirect to the uri specified in the last parameter is made.

As my error log shows, The try_files directive does not respect the root path because it trys to open the file relative to another location block.

Comment: You are missing the `$` in `$document_root`. Also, you are [passing uncontrolled requests to PHP](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#passing-uncontrolled-requests-to-php).

Comment: This doesn't change anything. If I open http://localhost/larvael a 404 error occurs and if i directly open index.php the interpreter says no input file specified.

Comment: The URI at the end of the `try_files` statement should be `/laravel/index.php`. You currently have `/index.php` which will be processed by the `location /` block, which explains the error log entry in your EDIT.

Comment: I've changed that, now the 404 error disappears but php keeps complaining that there is no input file.

Comment: Also, where are your files? In `/some/path/to/html/laravel/public/laravel/index.php`? Should you be using `alias` instead of `root`? See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45287201/wordpress-laravel-and-nginx/45297857#45297857);

Comment: the files are placed in /some/path/to/html/laravel/public. The index.php resides there.

Comment: did not change anything:

Comment: Are you using Windows? According to my experience nginx is highly reliable web server, so it's all about configuration.

Comment: Yes. My experience  is, that nginx works better with linux. As an Example with windows it completely lacks service support.

Comment: I don't know why this question get's downvotes. My Problem relates to a bug in Nginx. If you don't trust me, look at: [Using the try files uri directive with alias](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-the-try-files-uri-directive-with-alias)

Answer (score 3):

As @Richard pointed out in the linked Stackoverflow Thread, this seems to be a bug of nginx. For me this solution works with nginx:

```
        location  /laravel {
        alias html/laravel/public;
        index   index.php index.html index.html;
        try_files  $uri $uri/  @nested;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            include fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $request_filename;
            #include        fastcgi_params;
         }
     }

     location @nested {
        rewrite /laravel/(.*)$ /laravel/index.php?/$1 last;
     }
```

Source: https://serversforhackers.com/c/nginx-php-in-subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

may be some changes and updates you need to apply:

If you want to put your `laravel` project in a `subfolder` on a server with `ngnix-ubuntu 16-php.7.2`, so here is update ngnix config :

1) your nested(subfolder) isn't inside your main folder

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /nested {

        alias /var/www/nested/public;

        try_files $uri $uri/ @nested;

               location ~ \.php$ {
                        include fastcgi_params;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                                }
   }

location @nested {
        rewrite /nested/(.*)$ /nested/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

2) your laravel-test folder (subfolder) inside your main :

```
/var/www/main:
/var/www/main/nested:
```

then your config :

```
location /laravel-test {

    alias /var/www/main/laravel-test/public;

    try_files $uri $uri/ @laravelTest;

           location ~ \.php$ {
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                    fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;

                            }


  }

location @laravelTest {
        rewrite /laravel-test/(.*)$ /laravel-test/index.php?/$1 last;
}
```

Comment: This looks like a replication of my solution with multiple laravel instances. What's new about this configuration in contrast to mine?